# Disabling nether portal functionality

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to know how to disable the nether portal from taking you into the nether, and instead, to `tp` you somewhere else in the overworld. Is it possible to do this on a commandblock or with redstone in a single player puzzle map without mods?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `execute`'s `detect` syntax to increment a score while a player is inside the portal. Set up the objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add portalTimer dummy
```

Create a Repeat/Chain command block line (Fill clock in 1.8), and put the following commands

```
/scoreboard objectives remove @a[score_portalTimer_min=1] portalTimer 1
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:portal -1 /scoreboard objectives add @a[c=1] portalTimer 2
/tp @a[x=<x1>,y=<y1>,z=<z1>,r=10,score_portalTimer_min=60] <x2> <y2> <z2>
/tp @a[x=<x2>,y=<y2>,z=<z2>,r=10,score_portalTimer_min=60] <x1> <y1> <z1>
/scoreboard players set @a[score_portalTimer_min=60] portalTimer 0
```

The first two commands will increase `portalTimer` by one for every tick for all players within the portal, and decrease it by one for players outside a portal (to a minimum of 0).

The third and fourth command teleport players that have been in the portal for 3 seconds. Replace `<x1> <y1> <z1>` and `<x2> <y2> <z2>` with coordinates just outside (!) of the first and second portals.

The last command resets the timer after teleporting. This shouldn't be strictly necessary, but it's better to have at any rate.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mpvi_j9Thok).
It is basically a timer system where milliseconds before the player is teleported to the nether, they are teleported to another overworld portal instead. You can also do this with dispensers holding either mobs or items, that would instad fall on a pressure plate.

Comment: That would work perfect, but for some reason in my 1.9 snapshot, I get telelported instantly to the nether.

Comment: Just use a `/testfor` command. Google it

Comment: The instant teleport could be because you're in creative mode. Try putting yourself in normal adventure mode and see if it helps.

Comment: While it was great at the time, that video is *ancient* and outdated. There are definitely better options available now.

Comment: @crulcat You're right. That's the problem.